# Rewrite Search Results

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been through every single tutorial about mod_rewrite but i can't figure this out.

I want to rewrite search urls from `www.domain.com/?s=query` to `www.domain.com/search/query`.
So far i managed to achieve this using this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /(#[^?&\ ]*)?\?([^&\ ]*&)?s=([^&\ ]+)[^\ ]*\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/search/%3? [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that some queries will result in having several search result pages witch are accessible through `www.domain.com/?s=query&nggpage=n` (where n is superior to 2).

In that case, I want to rewrite that and end up with urls like: `www.domain.com/search/query/nggpage-n`.

Not quite sure how to acheive that. I'm seeking help guys.

Comment: IMHO you could try splitting the problem like handle the `nggpage` separately and the other case separately.

Comment: When you say you want to rewrite `www.domain.com/?s=query` to `www.domain.com/search/query` do you mean if someone types the first one you want the browser window to redirect to the second one, or do you want people to type the second one and it to be rewritten to first one?

Comment: When someone types www.domain.com/?s=query he gets redirected to www.domain.com/search/query witch has the same content. The given rule already did the trick but when it comes to handling the second variable (nggpage), thats the hard part. And yes @g13n I've already tried but with no success.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to decompose the rewriting in multiple steps. Something like this does the job, I simplified a bit your conditions:

1. Check if a search param exists, rewrite to the target path and set an `env` flag for later tests

   ```
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=([^&\ ]+)
   RewriteRule ^/?$ /search/%1 [E=redirect:true]
   ```
2. If a redirect is set and a pagination param is found, append a path for pagination

   ```
   RewriteCond %{ENV:redirect} true
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} nggpage=(\d+)
   RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1/nggpage-%1
   ```
3. Remove the pagination for page 1

   ```
   RewriteCond %{ENV:redirect} true
   RewriteRule ^/(.*)/nggpage-1$ /$1
   ```
4. If a redirect is set, let's redirect

   ```
   RewriteCond %{ENV:redirect} true
   RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1? [R=301,L]
   ```